# Simple Visibility Scenario - For Integration User

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing, visibility, criteria-based-sharing

I have a simple visibility question

There is an special user who should only have access to Account records marked with flag true.

Rest of the users should have complete read write access to account records

I can make OWD as private and share the Account records based on flag value to this special user (added to public group)

However I am not sure how to share all Account records as Read Write with rest of the users?

It needs to be a config based solution only (no Apex)

One option I can think of is create Roles for the special user and keep it at top level.
Share based on flag to special user role.

And rest of the users can be in a sibling role and then shared with them separately.

Is there any other clever solution that you can help me with?

Thanks

Comment: I'd reconsider having the whole OWDs modified because of a single user. Is it really necessary?

If it is necessary, you'll need to create another public group and put all profiles except the one user's there (or all roles except the one user's there). And create a sharing rule where the criteria would be e.g. Account Name != null.